# How many permanent SPECIAL points are available in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

Building a character in Fallout 4 gives you 28 points in total to assign to your SPECIAL attributes during the initial character build - compared to 40 points in Fallout 3/ Fallout New Vegas.

In Fallout New Vegas you could increase your SPECIAL attributes over the course of the game via temporary buffs but you could also permanently increase your attributes using perks and implants. Using all available perks and implants there was a maximum of 61 SPECIAL points available (reference: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_SPECIAL#Notes )

I realise it's day one and we've all got a long way to go but hopefully someone else can answer this question before I can:

How many permanent SPECIAL points are available in Fallout 4?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## There are 78 permanent SPECIAL points in Fallout 4.

- You start off with 28 points.
- You can find a You're SPECIAL! book in your Sanctuary home for another point.

  - Can only increase a maxed stat if a debuff like alcohol is used to temporarily lower one of your maxed stats
- You can train all your SPECIAL stats up to 10, so that's 42 remaining points.
- Additional Bobbleheads (for each specific SPECIAL stat) can be found, 7 points.

You can max out your character with 10 in each SPECIAL trait provided every time you level up you simply choose the appropriate training to increase your stats (as opposed to choosing perks).

Remember, there's no level cap, so you can keep on levelling and start getting other perks later.

[image]

So you start off with 28, but you can easily improve all of them to 70, should you choose to only train those perks starting at Level 2.

This means 70 - 28 = 42. Meaning the earliest you could max out all your stats is getting to Level 43, while every time you level up putting points in the stat you want to increase, provided you also don't find any bobbleheads along your way.

Additionally, some perks grant permanent increases in stats at specific times of the day or at a certain HP level, so those are technically also "permanent".

Comment: So basically if you kept leveling up you could become an ultimate survivor and conquer all?

Comment: @Bucky Yes, it's why Bethesda has implemented no level cap. You could continue playing with one character to the point where you have every perk and basically become a walking god.

Comment: Are there no other ways to permanently increase stats?

Comment: So what happens when you have maxed all your stats? What's the benefit levelling from this point on?

Comment: Perks can be unlocked, not just special stats

Comment: @Aequitas There are bobbleheads which provide +1 for a given stat. I'm not sure how many there are per stat, but definitely one.

Comment: There are also You Are Special books that give you a permanent bonus to any one stat. I've only found one so far (only two hours in) but I'm hoping there are more

Comment: Why level 44? If you need 42 level ups wouldn't that point to level 43? Or can you only start getting stat points when you reach level 3?

Comment: @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m - thank you for the prompt answer, very helpful. Can you add the additional information from thegrinner and Robert Wertz - 7 SPECIAL bobbleheads and (7?) You Are Special books.

Comment: Already added :)

Comment: Shouldn't the earliest level to have level 10 in all SPECIALs be 70 - 28 - 14 (+1) = 29? Taking into account the 14 points from books/bobbleheads.

Comment: Also, you can get all the SPECIALs to 11, if you use the bobbleheads while at 10, so the max amount used is 77, meaning the earliest level to max yourself out is actually 36. ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3s8x2c/bobble_heads_can_raise_special_stats_to_11_made/))

Comment: @Svj0hn The assumption here was a player would progress naturally and would not bother hunting for books or or the bobleheads, or were simply waiting to max out all stats (to get that 11 SPECIAL stat boost)

Comment: @Svj0hn If you can hit 11 with bobbleheads, could you also use the You Are SPECIAL books to push it to 12?

Comment: Special book can not be used on a 10 stat. A bobblehead can be used to raise stat to 11, but you must pick it up after you max out a stat. I have heard about one special book at the start, don't know if there are more.

Comment: In Sanctuary there's one SPECIAL book found under the baby's crib in your own home.

Comment: @SkyHiRider This confirms what I heard. I can't say I know of more than one book either, it may have been misinformation or misinterpretation on my part. Either way, the max is 11 in each SPECIAL.

Comment: The max permanent points are then 70 +7 for bobbleheads = 77

Comment: @SkyHiRider There are 77 usable points, but there are a possible of 84 points in the entire world.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that there is only the one You Are SPECIAL book.