# What happens if you use the 'you are special' book when all of your stats are at 10?

Tags: fallout-4

What happens if you use the 'you are special' book when all of your stats are at 10 or higher? I saw a question asking about the highest level you could get your stats to, but this specific condition was never addressed. Does it do nothing? Raise your skills higher than 10 or 11? I've already messed this up, and seeing as I have the ps4 version it would probably be faster for someone else to test this on the pc rather than starting my character over without touching the book.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that there are seven books. I do know that they don't raise points past 10, but I'm not sure what would happen if every stat was 10+. You probably just wouldn't be able to use that point.

Comment: Where did you read there were 7? This can be tested quite easily using the dogmeat item duplication exploit

Comment: @Timelord64 http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/242546/37612 The answer and some comments mention 7 books. This question was asked fairly early after release so I, among others, didn't know better yet and I guess just assumed there would be more books.

Comment: Ahh ok. The 7 your reading is for the bobbleheads. They reward +1 in the respective S.P.E.C.I.A.L stat

Comment: Its already quite obvious your asking about what happens once you max all special stats, and the answers addreds this, too. As such, I've rolled back your edit, as it does not add to the question. We discourage putting words in full capitals to draw emphasis. Use **bold** or ***bold-italics*** instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't raise a SPECIAL stat that is allready 10 or 11.

**However**, (allegedly, I have not tried this myself) you can temporarily lower a stat with chems (such as *Daytripper* for Strength), use the book and then have 12 points total ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3u2ntt/melee_damagestrength_optimization_capable_of_90k/)).

Comment: I've confirmed that this is possible. Not all of the stats are possible to raise to 12, but any stat that can be directly lowered by clothing, or the side effect of drugs or alcohol can be raised to 11 or 12 this way. The side effects from addiction however, do not allow you to boost stats past 10 using this method.

Answer (score 7):

The "You are Special" book will not raise your attributes beyond 10.

However, any of the SPECIAL increasing Bobbleheads will, if used on a stat that is already at 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the Special book when every stat is 10 or higher, it will simply have the option 'Do Nothing'. Then it will activate and go into your inventory like normal. So to answer your 8 year old question, it does nothing.

Comment: This was already stated in the previous answer, so what's the point of this answer?